# How it's possible to obtain a bank account and NINO without Passport in order to get a job?

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, eu-spouses

I have applied 1 month ago to a residence card, and now i got this letter with information that i'm able to work until they will make a decision on my application. Is it possible to open an bank account and a NINO with just this paper?[image]

Comment: Do you have any sort of ID? And on what grounds did you claim a residence card, as most applications require a passport.

Comment: When we applied for residence card we send our passports. So we don't have any ID valid with us.

Comment: In that case this document should be enough, you will be best to call nearby job center plus, explain the situation and they should book you an interview. Bank account is another story, as for even most basic one you may have to wait for your residence card.

Comment: Oh, and you can seek employment just fine while working on your NINO, simply provide it to the employer once you get it - it's fairly common among immigrants, although you may be taxed at higher rate.

Comment: ok, but how i will get the salary if i can not open an bank account?

Comment: There are multiple ways, easiest one is to get a cheque and cash it at the bank, although that won't work as you don't have an ID. So another alternative is to have the salary paid to family/friends account, and have them withdraw it for you. I did that for my first paycheck in UK.